# GWT: how can i format my GRID table

Tags: gwt, datagrid

I have a grid in my GWT application 
there are columns and rows which have data , if the data size for every row/column is same ,it works fine , but if some data gets larger , the whole format of my grid disturbs .

attached is the screenshot of my GRID , is there any solution for this ,like can i create a tooltip for larger texts or any other way .

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could define text overflow to ellipsis, so the text in your column will clip.

The text-overflow declaration allows you to deal with clipped text: that is, text that does not fit into its box. The ellipsis value causes three periods to be appended to the text.

```
.columnOverflow {
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

Comment: I've added this css to the label and then added the label.gettext inside my grid , but no effect , any idea ..

Comment: try adding  it to a div, the cell content should look like <div class="yourname">longtest111111</div>. Inspect with firebug.

Comment: additionally, to get a tooltip with the full text, add a title="longtest1111111" to the div.